# use unique script for several toggles

Tags: jquery

I need to use the jQuery toggle effect 3 times on the same page.

I have this code:

```
<input type="button" id="click" value="Click">
<div id="show_hide">Text goes here...</div>
```

and this script (i'm using it in Wordpress):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#show_hide").hide();

    jQuery("#click").click(function(){
        jQuery("#show_hide").toggle();
    });
});
```

Now my question is: how can i use the same script for the 3 buttons/divs? Using it 3 times with the different ids sounds redundant to me.
I'm tryin to understend if and how i may pass some kind of variable to the script to tell which div to show...but i can't find a solution...

Comment: show your html .You can use a common class .

Comment: Use a class? Put all the IDs in the selector?

Comment: Make sure your id's are unique and then add a class to each element that can be common to those elements that you want to show and hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind your event to all three buttons with a specific selector applicable to all of those. Then the handler handles the specific case

```
$('.toggle-button').click(function (event) {
    // $(this) gives you the specific button clicked
    // You go from here with the specific handler
    // Example:
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="click" class="toggle-button" value="Click">
<div id="show_hide">Text goes here...</div>

<input type="button" id="click1" class="toggle-button" value="Click">
<div id="show_hide1">Text goes here...</div>
```

Comment: hi...it works great. 2 questions: how to start the page with the toggle closed? then, if i wrap the button in another element (such as p or div), the script won't work anymore...

Comment: style="display: none" on the divs to answer the first question. The second question is relates to basic jQuery selectors. The current next() works for this scenario, if you change the scenario you would need to change the selector.

Comment: thanks a lot! what other selector could it be if the button is wrapped?

Comment: like for example $('.toggle-button').parent().next('div').

Comment: thanks for all your help. i've end up with this `jQuery('.show_hide').click(function (event) {
  var value = jQuery(this).attr('value');
  jQuery('#' + value).toggle();
 });` so i just need to assigne the value of the button to the id of the div. the only issue is that the value can't have more than one word in the name, but for the moment i think i can leave it this way...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo of how to do this with the shortest amount of code - http://jsfiddle.net/p8aWY/

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.show_hide').toggle();
});
```

Here is the HTML, using classes instead of ID's -

```
<input type="button" value="Click">
<div class="show_hide">Text goes here...</div>
<input type="button" value="Click">
<div class="show_hide">Text goes here...</div>
<input type="button" value="Click">
<div class="show_hide">Text goes here...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An amalgamation of the two previous answers which were both correct

Javascript:

```
//Listen to click on all inputs with type=button
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    //Goto the next div and toggle it's visibility
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```